# how do we input data from cgi scripts to c program.exe for gpio pins on raspberry pi?

Tags: php, c, linux, raspberry-pi, cgi

I am working on a small home automation project which involves controlling of a DC motor with PWM output. I was successful in controlling the GPIO pins on raspberry pi by using wiring pi library with Eclipse IDE for remote debugging and controlling all GPIO pins.

**Next step:**

How to interface this with a web server? I was able to control small LED (GPIO pin) using a PHP script. Can I invoke a program written in C, i.e. an exe file from a web server? It is OK even if it is multiple programs for 0 to full on states of motor PWM. To control motor speed using PWM from web server, how can input based on the current state of pin be used. How can communication between PHP and a program running on the server happen?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: An database, simple text file ?

Comment: you can call a program, from php, and pass arguments on comandline, or via a pipe, you could have a daemon running listening at a socket ...

Comment: Thank you found something similar http://www.raspberry-projects.com/pi/programming-in-c/pipes/named-pipes-fifos